# Вернуть родителю, количество выбранных элементов

Tags: vue.js

Есть `app`:

```
    <div id="app">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="q" @input="typeInput">
          <search-item 
            v-for="item in search" 
            :item="item" 
            :key="item.id"
            v-on:click="changeStateItem">  
           </search-item>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <p class="form-control-static">#{ checkedItems }</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Есть шаблон:

```
    <template id="search-item">
      <div class="form-group row" @click="clickedItem">
        <p class="form-control-static" @click="inStock =! inStock">
        <i v-show="inStock" class="fa fa-check"></i>
        Название: #{ item.title }</p>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Задача, вывести в `<p class="form-control-static">#{ checkedItems }</p>` количество выбранных элементов (`item in search`).

Вот сам код:

```
  Vue.component('search-item', {
    props: ['item', 'value'],
    delimiters: ["#{", "}"],
    template: '#search-item',
    data: function() {
      return {
        inStock: false,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      clickItem: function() {
        this.$emit('click')
      },  
    }
  })

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ["#{", "}"],
    data: {
      endpoint: 'http://' + window.location.host + '/search/autocomplete/?q=',
      q: '',
      search: [],
      checkedItems: [],
    },
    methods: {
      onClick: function() {
        this.$http.post(this.endpoint + this.q).then(
           function(response){
            this.search = response.data
        }, function(error){
          //console.log(error)
        })
      },
      changeStateItem: function() {
        //
      }
    },
  })
```

Сейчас всё получается, кроме возврата результата, в родительскую модель. 
При помощи `this.$emit('click')` получалось отловить нажатие на компонент, но никак не соображу, как таки передать  `inStock`.
Я хочу в `checkedItems: []` иметь те компоненты, которые выбраны ( `inStock == true` )

Я только полтора дня изучаю vue.js, по этому не судите строго.

Для меня это диковинный зверь. До этого работал только с `jQuery`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция [`.$emit(event, [..args])`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) в качестве первого аргумента принимает строку с именем порождаемого события, все дополнительно указанные параметры будут переданы в коллбэк подписки.

---

В вашем случае будет достаточно передавать сам `item` и значение `inStock`

```
this.$emit('click', this.item, this.inStock)
```

а в функции обработчике родителя изменять массив `checkedItems[]`

```
changeStateItem: function(item, inStock) {
  if (inStock) {
    // Добавляем item в checkedItems[]
  } else {
    // Удаляем item из checkedItems[]
  }
}
```

Для вывода количества используйте `checkedItems.length`

```
<p class="form-control-static">#{ checkedItems.length }</p>
```